# A resource for multi-country SIM providers

Tags: europe, online-resources, cellphones, roaming

I see that there are several cell phone companies that will offer a SIM card associated with local numbers in multiple countries, so that you can receive incoming calls at local rates in all of them.

I'd like to find one for two countries I am interested in (Italy and Germany, in my specific case). Googling around find some companies, each with its own list of countries. **Is there a more organized way to search through them, such as a joint list published on an independent website or a search engine?**

Comment: The cost of roaming is dropping a lot in Europe, so are you sure you need to pay the premium for multiple numbers?

Comment: No, I'm not. This seemed like a good idea on paper, but after checking around the rates from these companies are way too high. They are definitely not competitive with a dual-sim phone or two phones.

Comment: T-Mobile Germany (as an example) look to charge €2.95/day for unlimited pre-pay roaming in Europe, or a pretty low per minute rate, so I'm still not sure you wouldn't be best off getting say a German sim while in Germany, and using it roaming in Italy

Comment: I see, but that still doesn't make me available to **incoming** call at **local rates** both in Italy and Germany **with the same SIM card**, which would be my ideal situation.

Comment: In principle, it looks easy and cheap to take an Italian SIM card, a German SIM card, and bundle them on a single SIM with a dual number. The same exists already for UK/US, for instance. I guess that this is not a common scenario, though, so it's covered only by small companies that charge "business" rates.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find a complete list, as most websites usually only compare a few providers.

[This website](http://www.prepaid-wireless-guide.com/prepaid-sim-cards.html) has a couple of them.

There are 4 worldwide ones and one specifically for Europe which might be more interesting in your case.