# Are there sites to find simcard options that cover more than just one country?

Tags: online-resources, cellphones, western-europe

Regularly we get people on TSE asking what is the best phone/simcard for their upcoming travels.
As we do not do product recommendation, often the only useful answer would be a link to a site where they compare contracts and prepaid sim cards. But all of those I have seen do cover just one country, or even a smaller area or less wide range of options.

My main focus is on the Schengen countries and the UK/Ireland region, as that are areas where many people travel around and where countrywide options often only cover a few days of their travels.

A site which compares the 'travel Europe' deals for USA/Canada/Australia contracts would be welcome as well.

For international travel, a site that includes cheap rates in several European countries as search function would be very good.

Answers for other continents or groups of countries often traveled in one journey are welcome as well.

Comment: I do not think such a site will be available, or even if it is, would be up-to-date. Carrier agreements change all the time and there are all kinds of promotions available at any given time / day. The best you can hope for is a country-by-country breakdown.  Further, some people just want data roaming, others want voice and data. Yet, others are looking for a local sim with data, or a local sim with voice + data.  Then you have to deal with the fact that roaming rates in Europe are going away after 15 June 2017 .... its a tall ask.

Comment: AFAIK this is currently the best offer for Europe: http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Euro1

Comment: I am NOT asking for an offer or brand, I am looking for sites that compare and show what is on offer. I doubt there are non there these days.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24644/a-resource-for-multi-country-sim-providers -- I don't have the reputations to vote for the duplicate.

Comment: "Best" is opinion-based. And "cheapest" is meaningless if it doesn't offer the services you want/need.

Comment: That is why this question asks for sites that compare, rather than for single companies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as of 2016, there is no such site. Your only alternative is to create a page on the [Prepaid SIM Wiki](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Prepaid_SIM_with_data) for recommendations on which tariff to get for each region.

As of 2017 such a website would be relatively obsolete for EU/EEA member states, as all roaming fees have been abolished there.

Answer (score 1):

T-Mobile in the US [offers free data](http://www.t-mobile.com/optional-services/roaming.html) and 20c/min calls in most countries, but you need postpaid account, i.e. have US SSN or ITIN and pass credit check.